# What does "DS:[40207A]" mean in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-address, disassembly, memory-segmentation

```
0040103A   CALL DWORD PTR DS:[40207A]                USER32.MessageBoxA
```

What does `DS:` mean?

Answer (score 40):

The instruction is loading a new EIP value from memory at `ds:[40207A]`. i.e. there's a function pointer at address `40207A`.  (And it pushes a   return address because this is a `call` not just a `jmp`.)

The `ds:` means the instruction is referencing memory in the Data Segment - and can pretty much be ignored on modern OSes, since they run with a flat address space model (code, data and stack segments all refer to the same memory range, and memory protection is handled with paging).

The `ds:` is there to show you it's definitely a memory operand, and to remind you which segment it uses / show that there were no segment override prefixes (except maybe a `ds` prefix because that's already the default).

### EDIT:

A little elaboration - note that, to keep things simple, this is in the context of 32bit protected mode running Windows.

A *segment register* (CS,DS,SS,ES,FS,GS) holds a `selector` pointing to a `descriptor`. There's two descriptor tables: global ([GDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table)) and local ([LDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Descriptor_Table)), and the selector has a bit indicating which to use. Windows (almost?) exclusively uses the global table.

A *descriptor* is **basically** a *{beginning-address, size}* pair - there's more to it, but that's outside the scope of this post.

Windows uses a [Flat Memory Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_memory_model): each process has a 4GB address space starting at memory address 0, and uses [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory#Paged_virtual_memory) to isolate processes from eachother.

Since processes have this flat view of the world, they run with all segments using {0, 4GB} descriptors - and thus, instead of allocating per-process descriptors, Windows can use only a few global descriptors and have all processes use those.

### EDIT 2:

The [Portable Executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) format defines `sections`, which are unrelated to the x86 `segments` - even if there's some conceptual overlap. The PE EXEs can have pretty much any section layout you wish, but the normal is to split into (at least) code (read/execute), data (read/write), resources (readonly?). Splitting the executable into sections makes it possible to apply x86 page-level memory protection to the memory ranges.

### EDIT 3:

While the normal segments don't change per-process, Windows uses the `FS` register to point to the per-*thread* [TIB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) structure.

### EDIT 4:

See [this](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2005/readings/i386/s05_01.htm) for an overview. This is from an old document on the 80386, but the information still applies.

Comment: PE executables have multiple **sections**, but these are unrelated to the x86 **segments**.

Comment: I always thought they're the same thing, can you elaborate a little what the difference is?

Comment: @wamp: there, hope that answers your questions :)

Comment: No, the CPU has internal GDTR/LDTR registers that are accessed via LGDT/SGDT, LLDT/SLDT instructions. FS and GS were extra segments introduced on the 80386 that have no intrinsic meaning to the CPU; names were chosen since we already had the ES ("*E*xtra" *S*egment).

Comment: Can you explain what the segment descriptor says: `Z 1  DS 0023 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)` dumped from ollydbg.

Comment: The "Z 1" part is not related to DS, but the vertical column showing the contents of EFLAGS. The rest is simple: the descriptor DS references has a base of 0 and limit of FFFFFFFF bytes :)

Comment: What about `CS,DS,SS,ES`, are their values fixed during the application life time?

Comment: For all normal applications, yes.

Comment: This is drifting quite off topic. Under normal circumstances, I haven't seen the segment registers change while running in user mode.

Answer (score 5):

Memory addresses consist of a segment and an offset; DS is the "data segment" register.