# How to interpret segment register accesses on x86-64?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64

With this function:

```
mov    1069833(%rip),%rax        # 0x2b5c1bf9ef90 <_fini+3250648>
add    %fs:0x0,%rax
retq
```

How do I interpret the second instruction and find out what was added to RAX?

Comment: Assming you're running under linux, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611346/amd64-fs-gs-registers-in-linux) question might be relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "DS:\[40207A\]" mean in assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819699/what-does-ds40207a-mean-in-assembly)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code:

```
mov    1069833(%rip),%rax        # 0x2b5c1bf9ef90 <_fini+3250648>
add    %fs:0x0,%rax
retq
```

is returning the address of a thread-local variable. `%fs:0x0` is the address of the TCB (Thread Control Block), and `1069833(%rip)` is the offset from there to the variable, which is known since the variable resides either in the program or on some dynamic library loaded at program's load time (libraries loaded at runtime via `dlopen()` need some different code).

This is explained in great detail in Ulrich Drepper's [TLS document](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf), specially §4.3 and §4.3.6.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure they've been called *segment* register since the bad old days of segmented architecture. I believe the proper term is a selector (but I could be wrong).

However, I think you just need at the first quadword (64 bits) in the `fs` area.

The `%fs:0x0` bit means the contents of the memory at `fs:0`. Since you've used the generic `add` (rather than `addl` for example), I think it will take the data width from the target `%rax`.

In terms of getting the actual value, it depends on whether you're in legacy or long mode.

In legacy mode, you'll have to get the `fs` value and look it up in the GDT (or possibly LDT) in order to get the base address.

In long mode, you'll need to look at the relevant model specific registers. If you're at this point, you've moved beyond my level of expertise unfortunately.

Comment: I figured as much, but how do I get the actual address from a selector? I don't have a running process, only a core dump.

Comment: Yes, selectors are indexes (amongst other things, such as a flag that specifies LDT/GDT, from memory). You have to know where the GDT/LDT is, and I'm not _entirely_ certain you can actually get that from register info.

Comment: If you're afraid you're in long mode, I'm even _more_ afraid I can't help you further :-)

Comment: By "bad old days" do you mean 8x86 or 8x286?  I think the 8x86 segments were brilliant; even today, if the x86 architecture had a mode that worked just like virtual 8086 mode but with 32-bit rather than 16-bit segment registers, something like the .NET framework would be able to access 64GB of memory using 32-bit object references, which I would expect would be a pretty big "win".  If it were possible to use the top 4 bits of the 32-bit value to select one of 16 logical segments, each with an independent base address and scaling factor, the "smoothly" addressable memory could be even bigger.