# What does "[es:eax]" in "mov byte [es:eax], dl" mean in NASM x86 assembler?

Tags: x86, nasm

Can somebody explain what

```
mov byte [es:eax], dl
```

would mean in NASM x86 assembler?

Specifically the [es:eax] part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "DS:\[40207A\]" mean in assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819699/what-does-ds40207a-mean-in-assembly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of [es:eax] indicates an indirect move in which es:eax register combination contains an address and the byte stored in register dl will be stored at that address.

es is a segment register and eax is a general purpose register used in the address calculation.  I assume this is a 16 bit address model so the combination of the segment register and the eax register provides the complete 32 bit address for a far pointer.

See this [web page on basic instructions and addressing](http://www.csc.depauw.edu/~bhoward/asmtut/asmtut4.html).

And this [web page on effective addresses](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-effaddr.html) as well as [this one on addresses](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html).