# Assembler: Calculating a memory address with register base

Tags: assembly, ida, addressing

I have this simple assembler command:

```
mov eax, fs:[30h];
```

My problem is that I need to know what specific address is really read by this command. I found a lot of documentation about the assembler addressing modes but nothing about the **register:** notation.

Could somebody please explain me the math behind the address calculation?

Comment: Which specific assembler are you talking about?

Comment: The one used by Ida Pro. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Different assemblers have different syntax, so yes it does.

Comment: Protected or real mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "DS:\[40207A\]" mean in assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819699/what-does-ds40207a-mean-in-assembly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FS` is an index into a table of [Segment Descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_descriptors), which in turn contain a Base Address, which is added to the address. On win32, `FS` is used to access the Thread Information Block (or more accurately, the Segment Descriptor indexed by `FS` has a base address such that `FS:[0]` is the start of the TIB) and `FS:[30h]` is the location of a pointer to the Process Environment Block. On win64, `GS` is used to access the TIB.

Comment: Thanks for the description but I know what the code does. I need to calculate the memory addresses so that I can access the TIB by hand without code...

Comment: @Robert without code..? Well you can fire up VMMap and look at where the TIB's are (they're at the higher addresses)

Comment: Thanks for the VMMap hint, now I know the address where to search for the TIB. Anyway it would be interesting to understand the x86 assembler address computation.

Answer (score 1):

To get the base address of the `FS` segment in Win32, you can use the `GetThreadSelectorEntry` function (x86 only).

If you're writing a debugger, you can use `lpThreadLocalBase` value from the `CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO`/`CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO` structures which are sent to the debugger for every new thread or process. This points to the threads's [`TEB`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/TEB.html) and works for both x86 and x64 processes (on x64, the `GS` register is used for TEB).

Answer (score -1):

The best explanation ( and even with pictures ) is placed here:

http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs422/doc/art-of-asm/pdf/

Chapter 4 is what You should read.

Comment: The fs register is a 16bit register, therefore just adding the offset does not give you a valid pointer.

Comment: Ok, I edited it in order to keep the link to the most powerfull asm book, i have ever read ( and still read ).